# Why I am getting the segmentation fault in following c program

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

The following code gets compiled successfully but I am getting the Segmentation fault in the first line of the `main` function. I am not getting why I am getting this error.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
unsigned int prime=2;

void resetprimegenerator()
{
    prime=2;
}

unsigned int getnextprime()
{
    while(1)
    {
        if(isprime(prime))
            return prime;
    }

}

int isprime(unsigned int n)
{
    int i=3,check=1;
    if(n==2)
        return n;
    for(i=3;i<=sqrt(prime);i+=2)
    {
        if(prime%i==0)
        {
            check=0;
            break;
        }
    }
    return check;
}
int main()
{
    int t,n,i=0,j=0;
    int input[500];
    unsigned int answer[500][5000];
    scanf("%d",&t);
    getchar();
    while(t-->0)
    {
        scanf("%d",&input[i]);
        getchar();
        n=input[i];
        j=0;
        resetprimegenerator();
        while(n-->0)
        {
            answer[i][j]=getnextprime();
            j++;
        }
        i++;
    }
    for(i=0;i<t;i++)
    {
        for(j=0;j<input[i];j++)
        {
            if(j==input[i]-1)
                printf("%u",answer[i][j]);
            else
                printf("%u ",answer[i][j]);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I am not getting why I am getting the following error.

Comment: You have a large static memory to be allocated and I see in your code there is a getchar() following scanf() ? What are you trying to do with this?

Comment: @Gopi This is to fulfil the requirement of the input format.There is an "\n" in input buffer after each number.

Comment: the compiler 'should' be outputting error messages about using default layouts for some of the sub functions.  Because such functions as isprime() is being called before being defined and there is no prototype statement.

Comment: It is not a good idea to put huge data items on the stack. so move the lines: int input[500];
    unsigned int answer[500][5000]; to before main().  What I suspect is that the code is overflowing the stack segment.

Comment: this line, near the top of main: scanf("%d",&t); needs to have a prompt so the user knows what they are expected to input.

Comment: this line: while(t-->0) is difficult to read.  Use spacing, similar to while(t-- > 0)

Comment: this line: int isprime(unsigned int n) should probably be: bool isprime(unsigned int n) as the returned value is being used as a boolean. So all return statements in the function should probably be either 'true' or 'false'

Comment: this line: scanf("%d",&input[i]); should be preceeded by a prompt so the user knows what they are expected to enter.

Comment: this line in main(): for(i=0;i<t;i++) the variable 't' is already decremented to 0, so this second loop will never be executed

Comment: if the scanf format strings all contain a leading ' ' (a space) then any leading white space (for instance the '\n') will be skipped, then a following call to getchar() is not needed

Comment: these lines:          if(j==input[i]-1)
                printf("%u",answer[i][j]);
            else
                printf("%u ",answer[i][j]); can be reduced to : printf("%u ",answer[i][j]); as printing a trailing space on the last number will not be a problem.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
unsigned int answer[500][5000];
```

Assuming `unsigned int` is 4 bytes, this variable will occupy about 10MB of stack size. That's bigger than the size of a normal stack, what you have is [**stack overflow**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_overflow#Very_large_stack_variables).

The solution is to use dynamic allocation, or make it global / static. Choose according to your need.

Answer (score 4):

You are running out of stack space when you declare

```
unsigned int answer[500][5000];
```

Instead, allocate it on the heap; use malloc().

For example you can use a pointer to an array:

```
int ( *array )[5000] = malloc( sizeof( *array ) * 500 ) ;

array[0][0] = 1234 ;
```

Where `sizeof( *array )` is equal in value as `sizeof(int) * 5000`